# If $\mathcal{G}$ is a Lie groupoid, I want to show that $\mathcal{G}^{(p)}$ is a smooth manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry

If $\mathcal{G}$ is a Lie groupoid, I want to show that $$\mathcal{G}^{(p)}=\{(g_1,...,g_p)\in\mathcal{G}\times\cdots \times\mathcal{G}\mid s(g_i)=t(g_{i+1})\}$$is a smooth manifold.
I think that I have to use the fact that source map $s$ and target map $t$ are surjective submerions.
Thanks all for help.

Comment: if $f:X\to Y$ is a submersion and $Z\subset Y$ a submanifold, then $f^{-1}(Z)\subset X$ is a submanifold. Start with $p=2$, you just have to choose the right $X$, $Y$, and $f$. Then try induction in $p$.

Comment: So i should consider $s\times t:\mathcal{G}\times\mathcal{G}\rightarrow M\times M$. Next, i consider diagonal of $M\times M$. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little neat differential topology fact: if $M$, $N$ and $B$ are manifolds and $f:M\to B$ and $g: N \to B$ are smooth and surjective, and $f \pitchfork g$ (which is automatically true if either of them is a submersion), then the fibered product $$M {_{f}\!\times_{g} N }=\{(x,y) \in M\times N \mid f(x)=g(y)\}$$is a smooth embedded submanifold of $M\times N$. Proof: $f \pitchfork g$ if and only if $(f\times g)\pitchfork \Delta$, where $\Delta$ is the diagonal submanifold of $B\times B$, and $M {_{f}\!\times_{g} N } = (f\times g)^{-1}[\Delta]$.

Now use that the source and target projections are smooth submersions, together with the above fact, to show that $\mathcal{G}^{(p)}$ is a manifold for all $p\geq 1$, by *induction*.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with $\Psi$ up side down?

Comment: "$f \pitchfork g$" reads "$f$ is transverse to $g$" and it means that whenever we take $x\in M$, $y\in N$ and $z\in B$ with $f(x)=g(y)=z$, then $${\rm d}f_x[T_xM]+{\rm d}g_y[T_yN] = T_zB.$$

Comment: Ah ok, thank u. So the pullback of $s$ and $t$ exists and it is a good pullback.